# Top Android Apps

Tags: android, marketplace

Where can I get a csv file of top Android apps by category with information like app name, developer, app category, etc.? I am putting together a report for class and I have been combing the web with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

---

Update: With the new marketplace releases now and then, following links do not work. You can try something like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/top and get HTML and parse.

---

Here is what you want.

- [Check this url](http://www.android.com/market/data/free-brain.json.js). It's a JSON data for top free apps on Android Market.
- [Check this url](http://www.android.com/market/data/paid-brain.json.js). It's a JSON data for top paid apps on Android Market.

Comment: Those are the top in the "brain" category. If you go to http://www.android.com/market/ and use something like Firebug you can see where it's getting the data for each category.